# Generating .wxs file via MSDeploy package issue and WiX installer

Tags: wix, installation, msdeploy

I have an ASP.NET application and a Wix installer for it.In Wix project I referenced to web project.
I need to create .wxs file which contains web application files from Deploy Package.
I followed this steps http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2010/07/30/how-to-consume-msdeploy-staged-web-site-output-in-a.aspx , but it doesn't works for me.
The package successfully created, but .wxs file doesn't.

Comment: This might help while troubleshooting: In Visual Studio, change Tools » Options » Projects and Solutions » Build and Run » MSBuild project build output verbosity to Diagnostic. Do a rebuild and study the contents of the Output window. Also note that the current version of the article is for WiX 3.8, as it says at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the .wxs files are included in the wix project.
I usually create empty files and include them in the wix project then the harvest tool overwrites them.

Comment: Also, make sure to remove the read-only attribute before you overwrite the .wxs files. This is usually the case when working with TFS.